# using only negative lookaheads inside a regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to to check the sentence with regex that contain only negative lookahead. So if write

```
   ^(?!My Words)$
```

and Test string is `some characters`. I expect the regex should return true but it does not. should there be character consuming Match Character to effect the outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you provided means:

- The start of the string
- The following characters are not "My Words"
- The end of the string

There is no check in the regex that says the string must actually contain anything. More specifically, it **must** contain nothing. In this case the look-ahead doesn't do anything.

Presumably you want something more like this:

```
^(?!My Words).*$
```

The `.*` is just zero or more wild-cards, so basically anything. In this case the look-ahead prevents the string from **starting with** "My Words".

If you want to prevent "My Words" from appearing **anywhere**, something like this should work:

```
^(?!.*My Words).*$
```

Comment: Got it.. Thanks.. regular expressions are just embrassing.. so easy yet so confusing :)

Comment: or simply `^(?!My Words)` if you are only testing for match

Comment: @Anirudh Well, it depends. If you do a `string.matches` (in whichever language), that won't work.

Comment: @Anirudh actually what I want is the `sentence starting and ending with My Words` only. or to say having only `My Words` nothing else.

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls then why not use `^My Words$`..but if you are looking for lookahead it should be  `^(?!My Words$).*$`

Comment: This is super.. Thanks @Anirudh. I wanted to find how can the negative lookahead be used..